# Unable to Install PostGIS Extension for PostgreSQL 15 on Mac Book with M1 Chip and macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4, macos, postgresql-15

Issue: Unable to install PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL 15 on Mac Book with M1 chip and macOS Ventura 13.3.1.

*Steps I have taken:*

- Installed PostgreSQL 15 using the terminal.
- Installed PostGIS using the command brew install postgis.
- Tried executing the command psql -U boikoandrii -d postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION '3.2.0' SCHEMA public;", but received the error "could not open extension control file".
- Attempted to find the path to the postgis.control file using the pg_config --sharedir and find commands, but without success.
- Tried installing the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL 14 and 13, but encountered the same "could not open extension control file" error.

Additionally:

1. Installed Rosetta 2.
2. Installed pgAdmin version 7.1.
3. Installed PostgreSQL 14, 13, and 15, but version 15 is not displayed in pgAdmin4.
   Also, I want to fix an issue with displaying PostgreSQL version 15 in Pgadmin.

The psql CREATE EXTENSION command also does not work (syntax has been verified).

Please provide assistance on how to install the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL 15 on my Mac Book with M1 chip. Thank you!